# Replace "<" and ">" with "&lt;" and "&gt;"

Tags: java, android

I want to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` if it is not a part of an html tag.
Input will be a string that may contain certain html tags. It can also contain less than & greater than signs (">" "<").
For example:

```
String example1 = "-> <b> Bold </b> <-";
String example2 = "< <i> Italic </i> >"
String example3 = "<i>foo >> </i>"
```

As output I want to get:

```
String output1 = "-&gt; <b> Bold </b> &lt;-";
String output2 = "&lt; <i> Italic </i> &gt;";
String output3 = "<i>foo &gt;&gt; </i>";
```

So `replaceAll` doesn't work, I have to use a regular expression match I guess. Any ideas? Some other way?

**Note1:** 3rd party library is not an option because of certain project requirements.
**Note2:** We support only a subset of HTML tags(text styling tags: italic, underline, bold etc.)

Comment: Just for completeness, what about "<i>foo >> </i>"? Is it simply the tags you want to leave alone or also their contents?

Comment: @scorpiodawg I updated the question, check it

Comment: Oh and another one: do you want specifically HTML tags to be left alone, or anything that looks like a tag? What should be the output for string "<i><qxg></qxq></i>"?

Comment: There are a subset of html tags we support (about 5 of them), they should be left intact. So for that input output should be: "<i>&lt;qxg&gt;&lt;/qxq&gt;</i>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only support five html tags you could first remove those tags from the text.
    replace < and > by < and > and then add the html tags again. You `remove` <b> from the text by replacing it by for instance [b]. Do the same with the other tags.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-trival task.  HTML is not a regular language (perhaps it is irregular?) so you can not parse it using regular expressions.  I suggest the following:

### Option 1

Use this if you do not need to preserve white space.

1. Remove all whitespace from the input.
2. Split the input into tokens using "<" and ">" as the seperators; preserve seperators.
3. Process as follows:

   1. if the token is not a supported HTML tag and contains a "<", convert the "<" as desired.
   2. if the token is not a supported HTML tag and contains a ">", convert the ">" as desired.
   3. pass HTML tags unchanged.

### Option 2

Process each input line using multi character look ahead.

For each character in the input.  Convert characters are {">", "<"}

1. Is the character a convert character.
2. if no, advance to next character.
3. if yes, look ahead to determine if this is a supported HTML tag (this is the tricky part).
4. if not part of a supported HTML tag, convert the character.
5. if part of a supported HTML tag, advance to the character following the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't be bothered to use an external library then you would need to make an array with all the html tags and run it against the string.

I don't really recommend it because there are libraries for that...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming arbitrary HTML files, you have to isolate text nodes and run `replace` on those.

If you can't use existing libraries, I'd just write my own.

(JSoup can do this but it's an 'external library' -- that is, not included in the Java SE standard, but just re-implementing it is an option.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the strings are containing valid `HTML tags` . Following method could be applied to parse the strings to achieve  the result you looking for:

```
private static String parse(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == '>' && i != 0)
        {
            char c = str.charAt( i - 1);
            if (Character.isWhitespace(c) || !Character.isLetter(c))
            {
                sBuilder.append("&gt;");
            }
            else
                sBuilder.append(ch);
        }
        else if (ch == '>' && i==0)
        {
            sBuilder.append("&gt;");
        }
        else if (ch == '<' && i < str.length() - 1)
        {
            char c = str.charAt( i + 1);
            if (!(c=='/' || Character.isLetter(c)))
            {
                sBuilder.append("&lt;");
            }
            else
                sBuilder.append(ch);
        }
        else if (ch == '<' && i == str.length() - 1)
        {
            sBuilder.append("&lt;");
        }
        else
        {
            sBuilder.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```